# A Django ORM query using a mix of filter() and Q objects

Tags: django, orm, django-q

I'm looking to create a slightly more complex query that is written fairly easily using raw SQL. Here's an example of the query in raw:

> SELECT my,fields FROM sales WHERE is_paid = False OR status = 'toship' AND otherfield = 'FOO' AND anotherfield = 'BAR'

This is simple, it generates all the results that are is_paid = False and then a second result set for my AND matches.

Now I know about Q objects, I know about filtering but I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to achieve this in the Django ORM cleanly.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can keep building your Q object in a somewhat dynamic fashion.

Example:

```
query1 = Q(is_paid=False)

query2 = Q()

if status:
    query2 = Q(status=status)

if otherfield:
    query2 = query2 & Q(otherfield=otherfield)

if anotherfield:
    query2 = query2 & Q(anotherfield=anotherfield)

query = query1 | query2

result = model.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 15):

Although googletorp is right that you can't construct the query dynamically with a string, you *can* do it with dictionary parameters. Something like:

```
model.objects.filter(Q(**mydict1) | Q(**mydict2))
```

where mydict1 and 2 are of the form:

```
{'field1': 'value1'}
{'field2__icontains': 'value2'}
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
model.objects.filter(Q(is_paid=False) | Q(status='toship', otherfield='FOO', anotherfield='BAR'))
```

Edit:
You can't create the query dynamically the same way you can construct a string containing a SQL statement to be executed when completed. If you want to do this, I would suggest using an if state, function or what suits your use case best:

```
if query == 'simple':
    result = model.objects.filter(Q(is_paid=False))
else:
    result = model.objects.filter(Q(is_paid=False) | Q(status='toship', otherfield='FOO', anotherfield='BAR'))
for items in result:
    ...
```

This could be more complex, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: Ok I guess my issue is now. Let's say I have a query that is essentially this:

model.objects.filter(Q(is_paid=False))

And  I want to add another Q object to that query with some dynamic values to result in essentially the same query you posted, but it'd be dynamically created. That's where I am struggling on in this case.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Don't forget from django.db.models import Q

Answer (score 2):

This is a great way to do dynamic "OR" querying:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
from your_app.models import your_model_object

q_list = [Q(question__startswith='Who'), Q(question__startswith='What')]
your_model_object.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
```

if you want to use "AND":

```
your_model_object.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, q_list))
```