# Django query with variable number of filter arguments

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django query that fetches from `MyModel` based on certain conditions:

```
if beta:
    MyModel.object.filter(x=alpha, y=beta)
else:
    MyModel.object.filter(x=alpha)
```

Is it possible to eliminate the `if beta:` check and do it in a single line i.e. make the query filter on `y` only when `beta` is not `None`

Is this a good (Djangonic) way:

```
MyModel.object.filter(**{'x':alpha, 'b':beta} if beta else **{'x':alpha})
```

Or is it possible to do something like this (I know the following is wrong, but can it be fixed to give the correct meaning?):

```
MyModel.object.filter(Q('x'=alpha) & (beta && Q('y'=beta)))
```

Answer (score 8):

In such situations I'm using solution like below:

```
filter_kwargs = {'x': alpha}
if beta:
    filter_kwargs['y'] = beta

 MyModel.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

It is easy to expand when new conditions come in into the project requirements, but unfortunately its not a one-liner solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173575/2428955).

In your case :

```
query = Q(x=alpha)
if beta:
    query = query & Q(y=beta)
MyModel.object.filter(query)
```

Not shorter than other examples, but it could be cleaner if you were to add more variables to test.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it isn't good solution. I have problem to read and understand the code.

You can also do something like this:

```
objects_ = MyModel.objects.filter(x=alpha, y=beta) if beta else MyModel.objects.filter(x=alpha)

return objects_
```

For me it's more clean.. but it's only my opinion.

Comment: Yeah.. it's your opinion.. but it's not more repetitive. Python programmer always has to look for simple and clean solution.

Comment: A line of python code longer than 80 characters is always unreadable. It is my opinion after 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
objects = MyObject.objects.filter(x=alpha)
if beta:
    # Additional filter because of ...
    objects = objects.filter(y=beta)
```

Your way is simply harder to read. Python should be easy to read. Note that this only works right for simple filters (no multi-valued relations), as buffer mentions. Otherwise, your original query looks best to me.

Comment: Careful with this. [For multi-valued relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) `Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually know the details of that. Updated answer a bit.